# How to store several HTML form fields in one mysql table field?

Tags: html, mysql, forms

I want to store several fields from a html form in one table field. Here is the source code for the form. This is only part of the form, the form tags are there. Attached is a screenshot from this part of the form.

```
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="field checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Automotive" /><label class="choice">Automotive</label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Remark:<input name="rem_app_1" type="text" size="50" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="field checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Backlights"/><label class="choice">Backlights</label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Remark:<input name="rem_app_2" type="text" size="50" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="field checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Signage/Traffic lights"/><label class="choice">Signage/Traffic lights</label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Remark:<input name="rem_app_3" type="text" size="50" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="field checkbox" type="checkbox" value="IR" /><label class="choice">IR</label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Remark:<input name="rem_app_4" type="text" size="50" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="field checkbox" type="checkbox" value="LED lights"/><label class="choice">LED lights</label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Remark:<input name="rem_app_5" type="text" size="50" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="field checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Mobile devices"/><label class="choice">Mobile devices</label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Remark:<input name="rem_app_6" type="text" size="50" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The way it is stored in mysql should be like this, depending on what checkbox the user clicks,e.g.:

```
Automotive, Remark: blablabla
Backlights, Remark: blubblubblub
Mobile applications, Remark: skdfjasldfkj
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with adding a name field to those checkboxes. What language are you using for form processing? PHP?

Answer (score 0):

What backend language are you using on your server? Mysql is not a server language itself, but a means to communicate with a database. You need a server language to handle server requests. Check out [PHP](http://www.php.net/), [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NETDjango), and [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/). Arguably, PHP is the easiest to pick up, install, and set up.

Once you have a backend language, you can use that language's [Mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) bindings to communicate with your database.

Comment: I really think Django is great, but don't know if it's the right way to start with something so ORM based if you have never done it on your own (the form processing and database modelling). Start with PHP :)

Comment: Check out this one of several PHP/Mysql tutorials on the internet: http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql